# Ajax file upload using aspupload

Tags: ajax, asp-classic

I have read everything i could find. 
Yes, im still using classic asp

Im trying to figure out how to upload a file to the server using the aspupload component but with ajax.

I get a lot of php examples .net and client side that doesnt realy do anything

So how can i get the input content via class? Cause i will have more than one uploader in the page: `$(".file").val()` is not the way so what is?

I dont mind useing ajax on any form. I do know i can have `<form target=iframe></form><iframe name=iframe></iframe>` but not sure i want alot of iframe on the page

Answer (score 0):

it's complicated, check [jQuery File Upload Plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) By BlueImp, 
it's a nice component to upload files support Ajax, Iframe's etc ....
there is a Asp-Classic example that comes with the download file, check if adecuates to your needs.